# Edit markdown files in Neovim

Tags: neovim

I use neovim and try to edit markdown files with neovim.
I tried prosemd_lsp, marksman and remark_ls, but they all seemed to have one problem.
When I typed such as `- hello`, then I type the `<CR>` key. It will turn into

```
- hello
??
```

(I used the ? to represent the space)

insted of the expected

```
- hello
-?
```

So, how should I config to get to what I want.

Comment: Interesting observation, but what's your question?

Comment: So, how should I config to get to what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [autolist.nvim](https://github.com/gaoDean/autolist.nvim)

> Automatic list continuation and formatting for neovim, powered by lua